# Не могу понять как читать большое кол-во файлов python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу сделать скрипт который будет парсить имена файлов и содержимое этих файлов, а потом заносить все данные в другой файл. Парсинг имен я сделал, а вот читать кучу файлов списком - я не умею.
Поможете?

````
import logging
import time

parsdb = open('parsdb.txt','w+')
parsdb.close()
parsdb = open('parsdb.txt','a+')

def filenameparser():
    filecat = input('Путь к папке: ')
    fileNameFilter = input('Расширение файлов с паролями: ')
    myDBList = os.listdir(filecat)
    myDBString = '\n'.join(myDBList)
    replaceyml = myDBString.replace(fileNameFilter,' - ')
    print('Все файлы в каталоге: ' + replaceyml)
    parsdb.write(replaceyml)
    print('Был создан файл parsdb.txt со списком файлов.')


logging.basicConfig(filename="sample.log", level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug("\nDebug: \n" + time.ctime() + '\n')
logging.info("\nInformational: \n" + time.ctime()+ '\n')
logging.error("\n!!!ERROR!!!: \n" + time.ctime()+ '\n')



filenameparser()```
````

Comment: Возможно я не корректно понял вашу задачу. Но попробуйте составлять список из всех имен файлов, а потом читать все эти файлы в цикле for. При желании можете делать это в несколько потоков.

Comment: Оффтоп, а зачем вам открывать файлы с модификатором доступа `+`?

Comment: Привычка) Как-то само ставится, а я и не замечаю))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно считать и вывести содержимое файлов в папке.

```
import os

for file_name in os.listdir(dirname):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, file_name), 'r') as file:
        print(file.read())
```

Есть еще такой вариант. Рекурсивно пройтись по папкам

```
from pathlib import Path

print([open(i).read() for i in Path(dirname).rglob('**/*.txt')])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('parsdb.txt') as f:
    list_of_files = f.read().split('\n')
```